# Daily budget in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, budget

here's an issue. 
A student from Russia is applying for the UK visa. In the visa application there is a question "How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK?". I read on the internet (cause there seems to be no official information about it on the UK visa websites) that £50 per day is enough. But in case if the accommodation and meals are already payed forward what will be the final sum to identify in the application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In what way are accommodation and meals already provided?

Are you staying with a relative? In that case say so and a budget of £50 a week should be totally fine; all you have to worry about is transport and entry fees to attractions.

Have you already paid for them before you left home? In that case they're still part of your budget for the UK trip. Include them + the likely cost of travel and other activities on your application. You don't actually have to physically carry the money to the UK with you.

Is it provided for you by the university? Again say so and the low budget numbers will be OK. A letter from the university would be good here too.

Comment: Actually all answers are almost yes. Cause it’s a summer school and a student goes there with preliminary payed accommodation, meals and there’s no transport to the school. I suppose the only spending is like evening activities and probably some excursions. So the question is if people at the embassy understand it.

Comment: People who review these things (rarely actually in an embassy) will understand a summer school. However, they will need evidence of this. The student may need to get a letter from the course organiser.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official figure for a UK visit visa. The amount you’ll need depends on your itinerary and what you plan to do during your stay. If accommodation and meals are already covered, £30 or so a day should be sufficient, excluding travel costs.

Comment: If you are an impoverished student doing "studenty" things at a university with accomodation and meals already sorted, then £30/day strikes me as excessive.  I live in Zurich during the week, and probably spend about 10CHF/week.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I think this question is about getting a visa, not to show the lower limit. Larger the budget, more probability (if you have sound sources) that you get the visa: you are demonstrating that one do no need to work in UK. For a Russian already living on one of the most expensive cities of world, this should not be a problem (assuming the questioner is living in one of the two larger cities).